# How can I get the limit of $(-1)^{2n} $ when $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: limits

How can I get the limit of $(-1)^{2n}$ when $n$ goes to infinity? I checked it with wolframalpha but the result is $e^{2i}$, $0$ to $\pi$, why $i$???

Comment: $(-1)^{2n}=((-1)^2)^n$

Comment: What I want to know is what you put into wolframalpha

Comment: if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $(-1)^{2n}=1$, i.e. $(-1)^{2n}\rightarrow 1$ with $n\rightarrow\infty$, but not when $n\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @bluesh34 He put what any normal person would put but, alas, WA decided that $n\to\infty$ along reals, not along integers.

Comment: Maybe if $(-1)^{2n}=((-1)^2)^n$ Then the limit of $((-1)^2)^n$ where $(-1)^2=1$  will be limit of $1^n$... the limit is one????

Comment: lol....... @fedja

Comment: Correct @Salvattore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(-1)^{2n}=((-1)^2)^n=(1)^n$

As $n$ tends toward infinity, what happens now?

Comment: The limit is one?? $1^\infty$

Comment: @Salvattore, yes. Absolutely correct! :)